# In android is there a way to check if the service is already bound before binding to it?

Tags: android, android-service

I have multiple fragment activities and one of them is bound to a service that is constantly receiving messages. While I was switching between activities at one point I get the following error. I do not know how the List item is being clicked where the `service` is being bounded. In anyways I was wondering if I can add a check before I bind to see if the `service` is already running and connected.

```
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091): Activity com.MyApp.MyFirstClass has leaked ServiceConnection com.MyApp.MyFirstClass$2@42c84158 that was originally bound here
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.MyApp has leaked ServiceConnection com.MyApp.MyFirstClass$2@42c84158 that was originally bound here
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:974)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:868)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1960)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1943)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:529)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at com.MyApp.MyFirstClass.onItemClick(MyFirstClass.java:1140)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:313)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1529)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3560)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5277)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
04-08 10:34:54.674: E/ActivityThread(21091):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you ever found an adequate answer, but I just created a wrapper class I called `ExtendedServiceConnection` which basically had the ability to track and check whether it's Service was bound.

Just a tad cleaner then holding a global in Constants.

```
 private class ExtendedServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {

    private boolean isServiceConnected = false;

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Timber.d("Service Connection established with " + name.getShortClassName());
        isServiceConnected=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Timber.d("Service Connection destroyed with " + name.getShortClassName());
        isServiceConnected=false;
    }

    public boolean isServiceConnected() {
        return isServiceConnected;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
public void onReceivePause() {
    if (mExtendedServiceConnection.isServiceConnected()) {
        unbindService(orientationServiceConnection);
    }
    handleNotifications(mPackage.isIntentionalPaused());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way for doing this but you can do by 
Taking  service object as static and bind service through it

```
/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)
        {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get
            // LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            Constant.mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0)
        {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
```

in above code **Constant.mService** is static

so now from anywhere you can check service is bind or not by doing following

```
if (Constant.mService != null)
                {
                Constant.mService.stopService();
                Constant.mService = null;

                }
```

in above example Constant.mService is object on your service class

Answer (score 0):

There should not be some connections to service, that you loses. For every bindService() must be unbindService() - **with same Intent**. As i know, best way to bind in onResume() method (not in onCreate) and unbind in onPause().

Comment: I cannot unbind it as I need constant data all the time till the phone is powered off.. So I am using START_STICKY to make that work.

Comment: Are you really need to bind to service? Your service can just send [broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: I didn't say you should not use service. I sad your service can send broadcasts. By the way, there could be many activities that can hold this broadcast.

Comment: The service was sending broadcast but then had receiver issues as it was an anonymous receiver but it had to run between activities which was not possible as I had to unregister it.. So workaround was a callback.

Comment: Ok, using service. So, while didn't call onServiceDisconnected() method of your [ServiceConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) the service is still binded.